# Projection matrix OpenGL/GLSL issue

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl, projection

I have a problem while trying to apply a projection matrix to an object in GLSL.

Here is the GLSL code:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec4 originalPos;
out vec4 transformedPos;
out vec4 col;

void main(){

    col = vec4(pos, 1);
    originalPos = (projectionMatrix / transformationMatrix) * vec4(pos, 1);

    vec4 newPos = projectionMatrix * vec4(pos, 1);

    transformedPos = newPos;
    gl_Position = newPos;
}
```

It works perfectly fine on Windows:
[image: Rendering on Windows]

But it's not working on Linux:
[image: Rendering on Linux]

I know for sure is some kind of problem related to the projection matrix because if I omit the matrix application, it works just fine.

It is the exact same code and shaders.

Using lwjgl and Java.

Comment: Are you checking your shader compilation/link logs?  Are you using Mesa on Linux?  If so, are you creating a Core context?  If not then you'll be limited to OpenGL 3.0 functionality.  Which *doesn't* include `#version 330`.

Comment: Have you checked the code for OpenGL errors *before* running the shader? Perhaps you are using some Windows specific code that does not work OK in Linux?

Comment: I am creating a Core context and I'm doing the glGetError() at the end of every render operation. Just no errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
originalPos = (projectionMatrix / transformationMatrix) * vec4(pos,1);
```

Makes no sense, for a vector transformation. The '/' operator, when applied in GLSL to matrices does a component-wide division. What you probably want through is inversion, which is an entirely different operation.

Comment: That's a code for adding the colors, not really rendering

Comment: @mcat: Doesn't matter. Division of two matrices is allowed only in certain circumstances. Any because things happen component wise, given the typical transformation matrices, you get a lot of divisions by zero, which may either result in matrix elements becoming NAN or an error condition. Either way it's not something sensible to do (in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

It sounds weird, but removing:

```
originalPos = (projectionMatrix / transformationMatrix) * vec4(pos,1);
```

and the transformationMatrix, it works completely fine. That code was a test of lightning.

Comment: You probably ran into a division by zero error condition which prevented the shader from finishing, leaving you with a blank screen.